# Simple Javascript Login not submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following Javascript:

```
function TheLogin() {

var password = 'mysg';

if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
  top.location.href="main.html";
}
else {
  window.alert("Incorrect password, please try again.");
  }
}
```

and the following HTML:

```
<form name="login" style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;">
<input type="password" name="pass" size="30" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13) return false;" style="width: 130px;"><br>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Login" style="width: 134px; margin: 4px auto 4px auto;" onclick="javascript:TheLogin(this.form)">
```

I need this to do two things: 
  1. When user clicks button the javascript executes and thusly "logs them in"
  2. When user presses Enter key, it submits the button and "logs them in"

Desperate to get this working!! TIA!

Comment: What is not working? What do you get?

Comment: Right now #1 works but #2 does not.

Comment: What happens? How did you try to debug?

Comment: I fixed this actually!

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed using the below:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x != "password") {
        alert("Incorrect password. Please try again!");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

and

```
<form name="myForm" action="main.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Password: <input type="password" name="fname">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: That's... completely different code and behavior from your original question.